# Upload code files to Joomla site

Tags: file-upload, jce

We are trying to add Python code files to our Joomla site. We are using the JCE editor plugin, which does not seem to allow this (we've been trying different combinations wrt. the JCE settings). Has anyone done this before using JCE, or is there a different plugin for code file upload that we should consider?

Is there anything inside Joomla or JCE itself that blocks such file uploads? So far, we've been looking at /libraries/joomla/filter/input.php as well as the general media settings, with no success. I don't think this is blocked by PHP, or is it?

Answer (score 1):

By default, JCE strips non standard code when saving the article. The Joomla text filters may also block certain code but these can be disabled (e.g. for Super Administrators) at System -> Global Configuration -> Text Filters.

You can use a third party extension like the free or paid version of [Regular Labs Sourcerer](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer) or similar to insert PHP and other code into an article.

Joomla runs on PHP so you will probably have to call your python script from PHP. There seems to be quite a few ways to do this. For some examples, see the answers to the following questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/19735250/1983389
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/8303923/1983389
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/166944/1983389
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/5497540/1983389

Comment: Thanks for this! Let me be more clear about what we need. Directly pasting code into an article would be a good start, but what would be really nice is if our authors had a way of uploading python scripts as files - just like they upload PDF or image files. Let me know if you know of any tools/extensions to do this.

Comment: You can probably add Python files to the Legal Extensions and Legal Mime Type in Media Manager at Content -> Media -> Options -> Component and upload files using Media Manager although this might be asking for trouble especially if you have User Registration enabled or if you have have any untrusted user accounts. The other option is to use an FTP type of program either outside Joomla or inside Joomla (eXtplorer is one example).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the situation correctly you want to upload raw source files to a location in Joomla. I've only found two extensions that do an adequate job for this type of thing: [Chronoforms5](http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoforms.html) and [Docman](https://www.joomlatools.com/extensions/docman/) (not to be confused with the similarly named eDocman). Chronoforms is the cheaper of the two but it's method for uploading is also more mundane while Docman has the slickest interface both for the back and frontend that you could ever want but costs a bit more. As usual you get what you pay for.